# Swift project with Obj-C classes imported via CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to learn IOS programming in Swift.
So far I've a book on developing for IOS in Objective-C and Apple's book on Swift.
I've decided to start from a simple IOS app that uses a slide-out
navigation MMDrawerController.

I've installed the pod MMDrawerController via CocoaPods.

Since the installation of the pod did not use Xcode there were no any bridged headers created.

So, how can I start using this MMDrawerController written in Obj-C, installed via CocoaPods
in my Swift project?

Is it possible at all?

Comment: check out this [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) you just have to create a new .m file and the bridge header is created.

Comment: Also : [How to use CocoaPods with Swift project](http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=370)

Comment: @lukya, can you write an answer, I will mark it as THE answer. It actually helped me.

Answer (score 1):

For create Bridge File follow this:

Right click for create "New File" -> select iOS "Source" -> Select "Header File" -> Give File name and click on create

Now: import header file of MMDrawerController in Bridge file

```
#import "MMDrawerController.h"
#import "MMDrawerVisualState.h"
#import "MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers I'd like to make an answer. Thanks to the commenter lukya who pointed to a useful link.

This article helped me http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=370